# Show that there is a smallest closed set $\overline A$ which contains ${A}$

Tags: real-analysis

I'm a beginner student in real analysis and I don't how to start the question below:

Let $A \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ be given. Show that there is a smallest closed set ,$\overline{A}$, which contains $A$, i.e., $\overline{A}$ is closed set containing $A$ and if $C$ is a closed set containing $A$ then $A\subseteq\overline{A}\subseteq C$.

How can I start to show this statement? Any clues , hint...?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's two approaches:

- **Bottom-up.** If I give you $A$, what do you need to add to get a closed set? For instance, if $(n=1$ here) we have $A=(0, 1)$, what should $\overline{A}$ be, and how did we get it?
- **Top-down.** Let's say I have two closed sets $B, C$ containing $A$. What sort of thing is $B\cap C$? Can you generalize this to answer the question?

*Both* approaches are things you need to understand. The fact that they give the same result is a good exercise!

Comment: Note: the other two answers so far are both addressing the top-down version. This is definitely the easiest approach, but the bottom-up version is very important to understand as well.

Comment: Funny, I would have thought bottom up is easier.  ... Ah, Top-down *is* easier but it doesn't give you any idea what $\overline{A}$ should be.

Comment: I absolutely agree, but I would point out that the bottom-up version is considerably harder if you are working with the topological space only. @fleablood Over reals it becomes "easier" due to other inherent properties of the space (which I don't want to name to let the OP try and work it out himself). It's even more enlightening to only use the topological properties but IMO it is significantly more complex.

Comment: @DRF, well you can *"see"* it in the Reals.  But that doesn't mean you can prove it.  In topological space you can get it by looking at the definition of "closed set" and obey it literally.  Of course, it's easier after you've learned this several years ago than when you are learning it the very first time and you don't have an intuitive grasp on the definitions.  So HINT: look at the definition of "closed set".  It'll tell you everything you need (and only what you need) to add to A to get a closed set.

Comment: @fleablood couldn't help myself. The definition of a closed set that springs to my mind first is "complement of an open set" which tells me nothing about about what I need to add really.

Comment: @DRF can't help myself either.  Depends on the definition.  Use the *other* definition.  The one about limit points...

Comment: @fleablood The other definition is not usually a topological one. On $\mathbb{R}$ you get the definition of closed sets by limit points due to the large amount of extra properties (metric space; totally ordered linear space for the one dimensional case). The actual topological definition of limit points obviously works as well but the fact that closure under limit points means a set is closed is usually a lemma rather then a definition in my experience.

Answer (score 2):

**HINT**: Consider the set of all closed sets containing $A$ and then remember that open sets are closed under arbitrary unions.

Answer (score 2):

Hint.  What happens if you add all the limit points of A (Let B = A $\cup$ {limit points of A})?  What happens if you *don't* add all the limit points of A (A $\subset$  B but B doesn't contain all the limit points of A)?

Oh, and of course, if A itself is closed then ....

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb{R}^n$ is clopen (both open and closed), and it contains $A$. Take the intersection of all closed sets that contain $A$ (there is at least one: $\mathbb{R}^n$). This is, by definition, the smallest closed set containing $A$ and we denote it $\bar{A}$.

Answer (score 1):

To prove this you can use that the intersection of any number of closed sets is also closed.

Let $F_i, i \in I$ be closed sets such that $A \subset F_i \quad \forall i \in I$. Then $\bar{A}=\cap_{i \in I}$ is a closed set which contains $A$ and it's by the construction of it it's trivial that it is the smallest closed set containing A.